# Auto select value in UIPickerView based on location iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-location

I want to set some locations and have my app check if its by any of those locations and if the user is then I want the `UIPickerView` to auto select a value I set based on where they are at.

I am pretty familiar with objective c and coding for iOS but I really haven't done anything with core location. I have read somethings but I would like some help.

What I have is the latitude and longitude of the locations in a plist file. I can get the current users location and just get the coordinates with this code

```
  int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
  double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
  int minutes = decimal * 60;
  double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                   degrees, minutes, seconds];

  degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
  decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
  minutes = decimal * 60;
  seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                     degrees, minutes, seconds];
```

What I would like to do is compare what the users current location is with the locations in the plist file and if they are within a couple miles from any of the locations in the plist file then it will auto select a valve in a UIPickerView. I already know how to select something from a UIPickerView.

Comment: What have you read? What have you tried? Which part are you havin trouble with? Getting the location, choosing the right value from your location list or setting the picker?

Comment: What I am having trouble with is getting the location of the user and comparing it with the the location I have set and seeing if they are within a couple of miles from that location.

Comment: You should rephrase your question then - at the moment it is too vague and broad. Give examples of the location data you have in your list (coordinates, place names only?) and the location you've got from the device.

Comment: This is a much better question now! Well done with the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I just looped though the array like this

```
    NSArray *locations = [_locationDict allKeys];
NSInteger count = [location count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){

    NSString *locationName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[locations objectAtIndex:i]];


NSDictionary *dict = [_locationDict objectForKey:locationName];
CLLocation *itemLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[dict objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue] longitude:[[dict objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue]];

CLLocationDistance distance = [itemLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation];
    NSLog(@"%F",distance);

    if (distance < 100) {
        whatby.text = [locations objectAtIndex:i];
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `distanceFromLocation:` instance method (found in the `CLLocation` object)

```
CLLocation *myLocation = 'get the location'
CLLocation *storedLocation = 'get the stored location'
CLLocationDistance distance = [myLocation distanceFromLocation:storedLocation];
```

CLLocationDistance can also be replaced with `double`.  This is outlined in the iOS Developer Library [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html)

Comment: Ok I see how that works how would I run that though an array and find the one that is within like 10 meters?

Comment: So loaded the plist into a NSDictionary and I can compare individual locations and see how far away they are. What would be the best way to compare all the locations in my Dictionary?